# Implementations of single sign on, multiple profile?

Tags: identity, accounts

My employer is considering implementing a single-account, multiple profile system across their various web properties. The thinking is that SSO will be more convenient for users, but they might not want their activities on a dating site to be associated with their contributions to a forum on another site.

I'm very cautious about this approach - I'm pretty sure Yahoo! used to do this and it was enormously confusing. My hunch is that users won't understand having multiple identities behind a single SSO account on one network of sites.

BUT... that's just a hunch and I'm willing to be proved wrong. Does anyone have an example of implementations of this pattern (good or bad)? SSO, but you can create multiple public-facing "profiles" and use them in different parts of a site or network of sites?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's just because I'm a programmer, but I don't find OpenID's system confusing (well, at least [MyOpenId](http://myopenid.com)). When authenticating, you simply choose a 'persona' to send to the site, if any at all.